# How to update cell references when moving cells into same sheet as target?

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

How do you force an excel workbook to use itself as a source for worksheet links?

I'm writing a VBA macro to automate the process of adding an excel worksheet into a workbook. The worksheet (sheet1) takes only certain (but very many) responses from within the several sheets (response1, response2, response3) of the questionnaire. As a result of this, sheet1 contains lots of cell references that don't lead anywhere until after the macro is run.

For instance a1 in sheet1 "='response1'!b6". This returns a #REF! error before the macro is run (which is fine).
After the macro is run sheet1 is now inside the correct workbook, and "='response1'!b6" is now a valid cell reference.

Except excel doesn't realise this until after I manually click the cell in Sheet1, press f2, then press enter. When I do this the cell is correctly populated. The trouble is there are large numbers of cells.

1. Is it possible to construct a VBA macro that will simulate this process of selecting formula boxes and  pressing "Enter". Looking up people with similar problems, most have had the problem remedied by some combination of f9, turning automatic calculation back on, or ActiveSheet.Calculate or a variant. None of these have worked, it appears to be an issue with references, even though the references point to valid locations.
2. Otherwise, is it possible to use VBA to perform the same process as:
   Data > Edit Links > Update Values
   But in this case we'd need to specify the currently opened workbook as it's own source. Is there any way to do this?
3. When I manually selected the current workbook as the source under "Edit Links > Update Values" excel strangely repeats the worksheet name in the cell references, like this: "='[response1]response1!B31", which then fails to update when cell b31 changes, so this is not a solution.

Here's the code that runs on button press:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
'copy worksheet into responses
Dim CopyFromWbk As Workbook
Dim CopyToWbk As Workbook
Dim CopyToWbk As Workbook

 Set CopyFromWbk = Workbooks("Addition.xlsm")
 Set ShToCopy = CopyFromWbk.Worksheets("Sheet1")
 Set CopyToWbk = Workbooks("QuestionnaireResponses.xlsm")
 ShToCopy.Copy After:=CopyToWbk.Sheets(CopyToWbk.Sheets.Count)

Workbooks("QuestionnaireResponses.xlsm").Activate

'Put code to update links in here
ThisWorkbook.UpdateLink Name:="myfilepathgoeshere.QuestionnaireResponses.xlsm", Type:=xlExcelLinks
'End update links
```

Thanks for any help, this one's a head scratcher.

Comment: I have run into this problem before. I think (don't remember with certainty, thus the comment) that doing `TextToColumns` will take care of that.

Comment: Brilliant, worked perfectly. For others who have this problem, what I specifically did was create a "For" loop to cycle through the columns of my worksheet and then for each column perform a TextToColumns where only parameter specified is the destination which is the same as the source cell. Thanks very much Kyle!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great idea from @Kyle. For those who having trouble forcing cell references to update, `TextToColumns` works.

*However* `TextToColumns` draws an error if the source range is empty, so if there's any chance of that being the case use an if statement with no action attached to skip over those instances.

My successful code looks like this:

```
Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To 1004 
'Scans through row 2 from col A onwards
'If cell is empty, does nothing. 
'If cell is not empty, performs TextToColumns where source range = target range.
If IsEmpty(Workbooks("QuestionnaireResponses.xlsm").Worksheets_
("response1").Cells(2, i)) Then 'Does nothing if the cell is empty.
Else
Workbooks("QuestionnaireResponses.xlsm").Worksheets("response1").Cells(2, i).Select
Selection.TextToColumns Cells(2, i) 'Performs TextToColumns
End If

Next
```

All of my data is on the same long row. To apply the above to an entire spreadsheet, just nest everything between, and including, `For i = 1` and `Next` within another `For` loop with different letter replacing `i`.